# New PC Setup powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Question is: Can you guys help me clean this up and add error checking?
There are allot of different things going on in this script so here is the order in detail: 
Steps:

1. Run as admin newsetup.bat

   ```
   @ECHO OFF
   start C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Scripts\IEBlocker\IEBLOCKALL.bat
   start C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Scripts\RegFiles\Disable_NonAdmins_Installing_Windows_Updates.reg
   start C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Scripts\RegFiles\Disable_UAC.reg
   cd %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
   PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start- Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Scripts\New Setup.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
   End
   ```
2. at the end of the .bat it calls a newsetup.ps1 at the end of the ps1 it will reboot the pc.

   ```
   If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

   {   
   $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
   Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
   Break
   }

   function New-Sleep  {
   [cmdletbinding()]
   param(
   [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="No time specified")] 
   [int]$s
   )
   for ($i=1; $i -lt $s; $i++) {
   [int]$TimeLeft=$s-$i
   Write-Progress -Activity "Installing Software $s seconds remaining..." -PercentComplete (100/$s*$i) -CurrentOperation "$TimeLeft seconds left ($i elapsed)" -Status "Please wait"
   Start-Sleep -s 1
   }
   Write-Progress -Completed $true -Status "Please wait"
   } # end function New-Sleep

   $pagefile = "C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Scripts\Pagefile"
   $Wupdates = "C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Scripts\PSWindowsUpdate"
   $root = "C:\"
   $adobeReader = "C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Software\AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe"
   $adobeFlash = "c:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Software\install_flash_player_17_active_x.msi"
   $adobeAIR = "C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Software\AdobeAIRInstaller.exe"
   $java = "c:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Software\jre1.8.0_40.msi"
   $Bloatware = "C:\ClientApps\NewSetup\Software\pc-decrapifier-3.0.0"
   $log = "C:\clientapps\NewSetup\Serial&MAC.log"

   #Copy/remove & Import Modules
   Copy-Item $Wupdates $root -Recurse -Force 
   Copy-Item $pagefile $root -Recurse -Force

   Import-Module C:\Pagefile\pagefile.psm1
   Import-Module C:\PSWindowsUPdate\Get-WindowsUpdateConfig.ps1
   Import-Module C:\PSWindowsUPdate\Get-WUInstall.ps1

   Remove-Item C:\Pagefile -Recurse
   Remove-Item C:\PSWindowsUpdate -Recurse

   #Install Applications
   &"$adobeAIR"
   New-Sleep -s 5
   &"$adobeReader" /msi EULA_ACCEPT=YES /qn
   New-Sleep -s 40
   msiexec /i "$java" /qb
   New-Sleep -s 40
   msiexec /i "$adobeFlash" /qb

   #Run Bloatware remover tool
   & "$Bloatware"

   #Set Virtual Memory.

   Set-OSCVirtualMemory -InitialSize 6144 -MaximumSize 12288 -DriveLetter "C:"

   #  Enable Remote Desktop
   (Get-WmiObject Win32_TerminalServiceSetting -Namespace root\cimv2\TerminalServices).SetAllowTsConnections(1,1) | Out-Null
   (Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\TerminalServices -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").SetUserAuthenticationRequired(0) | Out-Null

   #Set Power Plan to High Perfermance
   Try {
   $HighPerf = powercfg -l | %{if($_.contains("High performance")) {$_.split()[3]}}
   $CurrPlan = $(powercfg -getactivescheme).split()[3]
   if ($CurrPlan -ne $HighPerf) {powercfg -setactive $HighPerf}
   } Catch {
   Write-Warning -Message "Unable to set power plan to high performance"
   }

   #Log Serial & Mac address

   $ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
   Stop-Transcript | out-null
   $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

   $OutputFileLocation = "$log"
   Start-Transcript -path $OutputFileLocation -append 

   gwmi win32_bios | fl SerialNumber

   $mac = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object { $_.MacAddress } | 
   Select-Object Name, MacAddress
   Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object { $_.MacAddress } | 
   Select-Object Name, MacAddress
   Write-Host "$mac"

   Stop-Transcript

   #Change Check for updates to disable

   Set-WindowsUpdateConfig 1

   #start windows updates
   Write-Host "Looking for Updates...."

   Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
   ```
3. What I would like it to do is added in I guess a try/catch for the applications to check if the applications are already installed and then a windows version check and if its windows 8 or 8.1 run a second .ps1 called Win8_apps_removal.ps1 script first and don't run adobe flash install. And auto calculate the virtual memory. I found the code below which I feel like will be required to check the installed program lists for already installed software.

   ```
   Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | 
   Format-Table –AutoSize
   ```

Comment: @ChristopherW This question isn't asking for a Code Review, and wouldn't be appropriate for [codereview.se].  That may be one aspect of this question, but the user is asking for help writing additional things that aren't already implement (`try`/`catch`, checking for installed applications, Windows version check, calculate virtual memory, etc.)  This question is probably "Too Broad" for [so], but it's **definitely** off-topic for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

For the part of installing all relevant updates, the command line tool WuInstall might help you quite a bit, it automates the complete update process with plenty of options - check http://www.wuinstall.com

Comment: WuInstall works perfectly as is. that part docent need any touching up.